# When saving endpoint in Remote site settings the Remote Site URL changed

Tags: salesforce

I want to invoke my external service in my Apex class on Salesforce.
So I add my external service endpoint in Security->Remote site settings.

My Remote Site URL like this
http://207.168.210.55:8080/testservice/jaxrs/salesforceService/restPost

But after I click save, the Remote Site URL is change to the 
http://207.168.210.55:8080

I don't konw why the rest part of my endpoint disappeared.
So does anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The [Remote Site Settings](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/configuring_remoteproxy.htm) only requires a domain (or in your case an IP) and a port. The truncated Remote Site URL should work fine for accessing your service.